# how to temporarily turn off/on multisampling for an OpenGL ES 2.0 render context in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es2

In my OpenGL ES 2.0 Android app, I render to an EGL surface with >= 2 samples; I obtain this surface by passing:

`EGL14.EGL_SAMPLES, 2`

as part of the `attribute_list` argument for `egl.eglChooseconfig()` in my `GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser`.

**(How) can I temporarily turn off multisampling for this render context?**

For example, I sometimes use the same render surface*between frames* to render my scene in flat fake colors for a picking feature, in which case multisampling it as least unnecessary. When I enable

> [x] Force 4x MSAA

in Android's developer options, I read back values completely out of the range that I've rendered, which for some reason doesn't happen otherwise on my multisampling surface.

Notes:

1. If possible, I'd like to avoid creating another (off-screen) render context without multisampling because it's extra work to manage its lifecycle and to communicate between the two threads. (The extra time for the occasional render pass on my main render surface is small enough to be okay).
2. `glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLING)` doesn't work on Android because the constant `GL_MULTISAMPLING` is not defined in either `GLES20` nor `GLES30`.
3. There is a constant `EGL14.EGL_MULTISAMPLE_RESOLVE` but as far I know, that can be used only to query rather than to set, the surface's multisample strategy, and neither of the two possible values mean "off".

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe if you define coverage solely using alpha? glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE). At least I believe that is what it would do...